# Error compiling Unreal Engine 4.24.1 after updating visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, unreal-engine4

I'm having a weird error after updating Visual Studio 2019 Community from v16.4.5 to 16.5. Even a fresh install of the engine will no longer build. I'm getting the errors listed below. The build doesn't fail until the end of compiling all modules:

```cpp
Error C4800 Implicit conversion from 'ADODB::_Recordset *const ' to bool. Possible information loss UE4 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\INCLUDE\comip.h 311

Error C4800 Implicit conversion from 'ADODB::_Connection *const ' to bool. Possible information loss UE4 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\INCLUDE\comip.h 311

Error MSB3075 The command "..\..\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat -Target="UE4Editor Win64 Development" -Target="ShaderCompileWorker Win64 Development -Quiet" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" exited with code 5. Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command. UE4 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets 44
```

I have not changed or updated anything on the Unreal Engine-side of the code. This error occurs during a build of UE4.sln, sourced from Epic's github repo. The build doesn't fail until all modules are built (it fails at the end of the build).

Seeing as Microsoft doesn't have archives of installers for VS Community, only Enterprise and Pro, I'm kind of suddenly stuck here because I can't just uninstall 16.5 and reinstall 16.4.5 (which is the last working version I was on before the update).

I heard sometimes setting "treat warnings as errors" to false can help, but I don't see a way to do that in Visual Studio.

Any insight into this would be helpful, Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

So, turns out something changed on VS2019's side in the update from 16.4.5 to 16.5, but the fix for UE4 can be found in [this commit](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/commit/25cefc81fe24c767eb995b0bb66b5611e0596973?diff=unified) on the 4.25 branch. Confirmed that this solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

### First Make a backup of your whole project (just copy it to somewhere else).

#### Afterwards delete the following folders in the project directory:-

- .vs
- Intermediate
- Saved

*you  just need to delete the* ***.vs*** *folder to solve the problem. The rest are just for a quick refresh of your project.*

Next open Unreal Engine 4, then under ***File*** tab click on ***Refresh Visual Studio Project***. On completion try to compile again. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For those who facing the same problem, here is the solution.

Step 1:
open the file **ADOSupport.cpp** on *[YourEngineSourceDir]\Engine\Plugins\Runtime\Database\ADOSupport\Source\ADOSupport\Private*

Step 2:
go to line **255** and modify it 
from `if(ADORecordSet && (ADORecordSet->State & ADODB::adStateOpen))` 
to `if(ADORecordSet != nullptr && (ADORecordSet->State & ADODB::adStateOpen))`

Step 3:
got to line **328** and modify it from `if( DataBaseConnection && (DataBaseConnection->State & ADODB::adStateOpen))` to `if( DataBaseConnection != nullptr && (DataBaseConnection->State & ADODB::adStateOpen))`

Step 4: Build the solution and enjoy!

Comment: nope, link is broken. Linking to other plattform is not cool, cause you don't have control about the linkage.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the new line of code, like on the video tutorial:
Arguments.Add("/wd4800"); // 4800: Implicit conversion from 'type' to bool. Possible information

https://youtu.be/KXIv4y51fyw

That fix me that issue.

Comment: Please write relevant sections of the answer here itself as links might change over time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and this solved it:

*File Path*

YOURENGINEPASS\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\Platform\Windows

*File to change*

VCToolChain.cs

After line 456 add the following line:

```
Arguments.Add("/wd4800"); // 4800: Implicit conversion from 'type' to bool. Possible information
```